# Getting Cross thread operation exception while debugging but not at runtime.How do I overcome this?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a multiline text box where I am printing logs from a socket receive method.
Once I get a client connection I am spawning a thread to handle the same.From this handler I update the details in the text box.I got a cross thread exception while running the application,so I got around it by inheriting the ConnectionHandler class from the Form class and checking for InvokeRequired.
But now I get the cross thread exception when i debug the code but not when I run without Debugging.Am i using the right approach here?

I am using the following code for updating the textbox

```
private void WriteToLog(string message)
    {

        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { WriteToLog(message); }));
        }
        else
        {
            ClientObj.textBox_Log.AppendText(message + "\r\n");
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you're updating a TextBox, you should call InvokeRequired on the TextBox control itself. Then you can ensure that the invoked code executes on the same GUI thread as TextBox was created on. (Inheriting a class from Form will give you the 'InvokeRequired' property, but the property won't give you a meaningful answer if your ConnectionHandler was not created on the same thread as the application's main form)

Comment: @Baldrick when i used the control directly i got the following exception "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created."